# Error; number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to run a really simple script in R but I keep having this message : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
I've try ifelse, it doesn't work.
Here's my script:

```
estodemog <-
  function(mida, tmax = 50, grafic = T) {
    S1 = 0.480 ##supervivència del primer any de vida (de volander a 1 any)
    S2 = 0.574 #supervivència del segon any de vida
    S3 = 0.574 #supervivència del tercer any de vida
    S4 = 0.889 #supervivència del quart any de vida
    Sa = 0.889 #supervivència posteriors
    F2 = 0.286 #fecunditat (volandersper femella) de las femelles de dos anys
    F3 = 0.400 #fecunditat amb 3 anys
    Fa = 1.129 #fecunditat amb 4 o més anys
    Sr = 0.5 #quocient sexual (sex ratio)
    R2 = 0.161 #taxa de reclutament amb dos anys d’edat
    R3 = 0.680 #taxa de reclutament amb tres anys d’edat
    R4 = 0.934 #taxa de reclutament amb quatre anys d’edat
    n <- matrix(rep(0, tmax * 2), ncol = tmax)
    n[, 1] <- c(round(mida * 0.3), round(mida * 0.7))
    rownames(n) <- c("juvenils", "adults")
    for (t in 2:tmax) {
      n[, t] <- c(
        rbinom(1, n[1 , t - 1], S2 * R2 * F2 * Sr) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], S3 * R3 * F3 * Sr) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], Sa * R4 * Fa * Sr) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], Sa * Fa * Sr),
        
        rbinom(1, n[1 , t - 1], S2),
        
        rbinom(1, n[1 , t - 1], S3),
        
        rbinom(1, n[1 , t - 1], S4) +
          
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], Sa)
      )
      if (sum(n[, t]) == 0)
        break
    }
    if (grafic)
      matplot2(n,
               lty = 1,
               lwd = 4,
               col = c("blue", "red"))
    return(t)
  }

estodemog(50)
```

thnx

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this part of the function:

```
n[, t] <- c(
        rbinom(1, n[1 , t - 1], S2 * R2 * F2 * Sr) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], S3 * R3 * F3 * Sr) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], Sa * R4 * Fa * Sr) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], Sa * Fa * Sr),
        
        rbinom(1, n[1 , t - 1], S2),
        
        rbinom(1, n[1 , t - 1], S3),
        
        rbinom(1, n[1 , t - 1], S4) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], Sa)
      )
```

You are trying to assign a vector of length 4 (created by `c(rbinom(...) + ..., ..., ..., ...)` to a vector of length 2 `n[, t]`.

If you reduce the vector length you create to 2, it runs without an error. This is likely not producing the result you are looking for, but just for demonstration, here is a modification of your code that does not raise an error:

```
n[, t] <- c(
        rbinom(1, n[1 , t - 1], S2 * R2 * F2 * Sr) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], S3 * R3 * F3 * Sr) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], Sa * R4 * Fa * Sr) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], Sa * Fa * Sr),
        
        rbinom(1, n[1 , t - 1], S4) +
          rbinom(1, n[2 , t - 1], Sa)
      )
```

If you could update your question to provide some context and a description of what you are trying to achieve, it might be possible to help you further.